# Prove every inﬁnite recursively enumerable subset of $\Bbb N$ contains an inﬁnite recursive subset

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability, recursion

Given that:

> An inﬁnite subset of $\Bbb N$ is recursive if and only if it is the range of a strictly increasing recursive function.

Now I wonder if It can be proved that:

> Every inﬁnite recursively enumerable subset of $\Bbb N$ contains an inﬁnite recursive subset.

From the definition of recursively enumerable set, it is the range of a recursive function $f$. Although in the definition, the $f$ is not necessarily strictly increasing, I wonder if I can use this function to deﬁne a new one which is strictly increasing recursive function and whose image is a subset of $im(f)$. And hence reach the conclusion.

So may I please ask if it can be done? How to do that exactly? Thanks in advance!

**Note**: It is from a math course. And I have not learnt about the related things about computer science (for instance, I have not learnt about the Turing machine). So sorry I cannot understand explanations which involves the usage of terms in computer science. May I please ask for a mathematical approch please? 
Thanks!

**EDIT**: The definition of recursive function is given by:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let $A$ be an infinite r.e. subset of $\mathbb N;$ so $A$ is the range of a recursive function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N.$ For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $g(n)=\max\{f(1),f(2),\dots,f(n)\};$ then $g$ is a recursive function, and the range of $g$ is an infinite recursive subset of $A.$

Comment: What you gave is not the right definition of recursive function.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I have been given that a recursive function is recursive if it is both partial recursive and total. I'll edit to add the orginal version of the definition.

Comment: No, that's not the right definition.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo So may I please ask what is the right one? It is given by my textbook and we are taught to use this version...

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo What do you mean? That seems right to me.

Comment: @Noah Conditions 1-5 are not enough. In particular, all functions obtained that way are total, and Ackermann's function would not be recursive.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Minimalisation is allowed to be used, which can allow partial recursive function to be generated.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Sorry, ignore the noise.

Comment: What is the definition of "minimalisation"?

Comment: @RobArthan I have edited to give a definition.

Comment: @PropositionX: thanks. The $\mu$ operator you have defined should be referred to as  "minimisation" or "minimization". Your textbook is wrong to refer to it as "minimalisation".  Using $\mu$ and the given recursive function $f`(x)$ whose range is infinite, you can define a function $g(x)$ that enumerates a strictly increasing subset of the range of $f$.

Comment: @RobArthan I am trying on this track and is it applying minimalization to find the least value of the characteristic function is true and greater then the former output number? Is the idea correct? I have trouble how to formalize it and write it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it looks like your definition of partial recursive function is indeed incorrect: it is missing the [primitive recursion clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function#Definition). Without this clause, we get a strictly smaller class of functions. In fact, it's not hard to show that the function $f(n)=n^n$ grows faster than every function you can express using your system.

So how do we solve the problem *with the correct definition*? Suppose I have an r.e. set $X$. Since $X$ is r.e., we have $X=ran(f)$ for some recursive function $f$.  Intuitively, I can find an infinite recursive subset $S\subseteq X$ as follows: each time I see $f$ enumerate some element of $X$ bigger than every element previously, I put it in $S$. The "bigger than every element previously" means that this set is in fact intuitively recursive: if I want to know whether $n\in S$, I wait until this process either puts $n$ into $S$ (in which case $n\in S$) or puts something bigger than $n$ into $S$ (in which case $n\not\in S$ since we can never "come back" to it).

Now we have to implement this strategy. We first define an auxiliary function $i$ which counts when $f$ "goes up":

- $i(0)=0$,
- $i(n+1)$ is the least $x$ such that $f(x)>f(i(n))$. (We could add the requirement that $x>i(n)$ but by induction we can show that this won't be necessary).

If we can show that $i$ is recursive, then we'll let $g(x)=f(i(x))$; it's clear that $g$ is increasing, and $ran(g)\subseteq X$, so we'll be done.

So how do we show that $i$ is recursive? This is where the primitive recursion scheme comes in handy. We have $i(n+1)=x$ iff $x$ is the least number such that $f(x)>i(n)$, that is, the least $x$ such that $i(n)+1-f(x)=0$ (I use "$-$" to denote natural subtraction here). So $i$ can be defined by primitive recursion as:

- $i(0)=0$,
- $i(n+1)=h(i(n))$, where $h(a)=\mu x (a+1-f(x)=0)$.

And now we're done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My textbook does mention that primitive recursive functions are recursive latter.

Comment: @PropositionX I'm curious, what textbook are you using? (I'm curious whether they just forgot to add the prim. rec. scheme, or whether there's something else going on.)

Comment: This is a 500-page notes given by our lecture, which has 3 chapters on recursion theory. Latter in the notes we will learn about computability and Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: As mentioned in the book, wherever a minimalisation is used, it can be shown that it can be replaced somehow with a primitive recursion. I think that is a reason why it discuss primitive recursion latter.

Comment: What is $\mu$ representing here?

Comment: @David $\mu$ is the [$\mu$ operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C_operator) - "$\mu x(P(x))$" denotes (if it exists) the smallest number with property $P$. So in this case, the smallest $x$ such that $a+1-f(x)=0$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you, I was just making sure!

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I was also stuck with the same problem. I was trying to find out explicitly an infinite computable subset of the diagonal halting set but couldn't succeed.

Comment: Are you sure that the definition is wrong? As far as I know, Gödel's beta function can be coded using only minimization, multiplication and addition (and constants), and it can in turn be used to code sequences, which can be used to emulate prmitive recursion.

Comment: @Veky I am pretty sure of this. Try writing out the details of your approach, I am highly confident that it will break down.

Comment: I'm quite sure the burden of proof should be on you (you claim that published material is wrong) but so be it. From minimization, subtraction and addition define ordering (<=). From it and multiplication define equality (=). From minimization, ordering and multiplication define quotient. From it, multiplication and subtraction define remainder. From it define beta function. From beta and minimization define coding of sequences. From it and minimization define (.)_ and lh. From it define primitive recursion in a standard way (last item in a minimal inductive sequence satisfying initial cond).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I may be mistaken, but perhaps the 6th line from the bottom of your answer s/b $f(x)>f(i(n))$, since $i(n)$ is a function for finding the x's where $f$ increases. $i$ is not a subset of the range of $f$. The 5th line from bottom s/b something different too. Maybe $f(i(n+1))-f(x)>0$? Also, the second line from the bottom is wrong, I believe. Otherwise, $i(1) = h(i(0)) = \mu x (0+1-f(x)=0)$. But we aren't guaranteed that there exists an $f(x)$ that equals 1.